# rails i18n passed params get lost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I started using *i18n* with my app, but all the pages that i access by passing a parameter with the ***link_to*** isn't working.

so, let's say i'm currently on this page

```
/ar/browse?type=art
```

that i got to via clicking on this ***link_to***

```
<%= link_to "/ART/", browse_url(:type => "art")%>
```

then i decided to change the language via clicking on this:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "en", locale: 'en', :class => 'my-navbar-link' %>
```

after changing the language, that's what i get directed to

```
/en/browse?class=my-navbar-link
```

the ***type*** parameter get lost after i change the language. and as a result it doesn't direct me to the correct page

hope i made it clear. i'm not sure how i can fix it :/

thank you in advance.

Comment: where's the link to line ?

Comment: i'm not sure i get you. what do you mean?

Comment: you said the link_to is not working, please add the link_to part from your code to the question

Comment: updated. it's not just this one actually, anywhere i pass a params.

Comment: still don't know how you got that `class=my-navbar-link` but you could try add the current filters to the url, but you'll need to refine it a bit to remove the controller, and action from the params `<%= link_to "/ART/", browse_url(params.merge(type: :art)%>`

Comment: I don't think you get what i'm facing here. just edited the question. hope it's clear now.

Comment: I think the problem is that all these arguments are passed to the link_to, try something like `<%= link_to_unless_current("en", {locale: 'en'}), class: 'my-navbar-link' %>`

Comment: appreciate your effort, but that didn't work :c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are incorrectly passing arguments to `link_to_unless_current`. The following is what you need to do:

```
link_text = "en" # or whatever you like
html_class = "my-navbar-link"

link_to_unless_current link_text,
                       {locale: "en", type: params[:type]},
                       {class: html_class}
```

i.e. you need to separate the link options from the HTML options.

Comment: yay! it worked xD. thank u, thank u, thank u. oh i got it now!