# Locale switch in Rails causing url params to be dropped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, locale, rails-i18n

Until recently, I have been using `params.merge` to handle this, but having been alerted to an XSS vulnerability needed to find a better way to handle locale switching. Most pages are now completely fine, but certain urls will have params that I need to keep, for example:

`movies/123456/seat?ticket_id=1670&locale=en&time_type=2`

The locale switch is now handled like so from the navbar:

```
<li><%= link_to "English", locale: "en" %></li>
```

Unfortunately, switching the locale (EG; to Japanese) results in the following:

`movies/123456/seat?locale=ja`

Is there any way that I can retain the parameters (without using params.merge as before) or do I need to re-work large chunks of my application to resolve this?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#managing-the-locale-across-requests

Comment: I probably should have said that was my first visit with this haha! Unfortunately I still have the issue of my url dropping any params when I switch. In the given example, I can see the "lost params url" when hovering over the option so I have definitely got something wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29002068/rails-i18n-passed-params-get-lost#29008971

Comment: Unfortunately that solution also exposes params to the view - I can very easily XSS inject code back into my app if I do that. For example, adding `seat: params[:seat]` means that adding `/?seat="><svg%2Fonload%3Dconfirm(%2FXSS-IS-HERE%2F)>` to the browser makes a nasty little popup appear.

Comment: I would consider if you can solve part of the problem by creating better routes. For example: `/tickets/1670/seats`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a method to whitelist and sanitize the params:

```
module ParamsHelper
  def merge_and_santize_params(*whitelist)
     params.permit(*whitelist)
           .transform_values! { |v| sanitize v }
           .merge(locale: I18n.current_locale)
  end
end
```

---

```
<li><%= link_to "English", merge_and_santize_params(:time_type, :ticket_id) %></li>
```

This uses [ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#M002163) which is better than nothing but may still be vulnerable to well crafted attacks.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be a good short-term solution while I make routing changes as you mentioned in the comment on the original question.